# How to make string to json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, string

I have below string

```
'[{\'Question\': \'a Names and Roles (if known)\'}]'
```

I need to convert it into JSON.

I tried `JSON.parse(s)`

```
I got error SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2
```

and also

```
> eval(s)
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

Any help would be really appreciable

Comment: How is that string generated? From a quick glance a `\'` in front of the first "Question" seems to fix it, such that `JSON.parse()` might work.

Comment: @Sirko thank you for your reply .. it is generated a body response from rest api call ok can you please help me how should I do that

Comment: adding `\'` will still not work

Comment: I got SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2

Comment: @RajarshiDas Can you kindly edit this to take out the vertical scroll in the JSON string?

Comment: I don't think the string is properly formatted so JSON to parse it.

Comment: JSON needs double quotes. With single quotes it may be correct JS, but not JSON. Google for JSON spec, it's simple.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>**'[{*Question\':** at the point of asterisk you need a `\'` don't you?</strike>

So it should be

```
'[{\'Question\': \'a Names and Roles..
```

**EDIT**

Found this after a bit of research. **Problem is with the single quote**. Replace them with double quotes, you are good to go. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lka7jm22/), to check this out in action.

Additionally, I had to modify `"[\'NA\']"` in your string, to get it to working. That is also invalid JSON. If it is an array that you want it to be, you should put it like `[\"NA\"]`.

Comment: I got SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 2

Comment: @RajarshiDas Edited my answer. Check it out now.

Comment: Still not valid JSON.

Comment: @Frax Are you replying me? I just go this to work in my Chrome browser, after the changes I have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you need to pass string inside JSON.parse(s).
Please make sure s is a string